# ImageDrawable not set in desire imageview size

Tags: android

I'm trying to set drawable at ImageView where I'm generation drawable by image bitmap of intrinsicWidth and height 160 and imageview width is 36dp but still image not setting in 36dp imageview.
Image is looking more smaller than imageview.

Please help me.

```
             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_doctor"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


        Drawable drawable11 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),myBitmap);
        Log.e("", ""+drawable11.getIntrinsicWidth()+"::"+drawable11.getIntrinsicHeight());
        imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable11);
```

Here I'm getting 160::160 in logcat.

Answer (score 2):

if you have bitmap already then use **imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)** instead of converting bitmap to drawable.

Comment: Actually i'm creating circular image drawable by this bitmap so I can't use directly dude.